# Delete message command, its work only for Owner, Admin and Moderator

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I am code the Discord bot for my server. I want to add a command for my bot, the command will clear a text channel, and will only allow people with Owner, Admin, Moderator role.

In the code, it's have `if(!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "**Owner**")`, I have this role but I can't delete message. But when I give 3 roles (Owner, Admin and Moderator) for me, I can use it.

So I need to fix: 1 of 3 roles can still use it.

The code is here:

```js
case 'clear': 
    if(!args[1]) 
        return message.reply('Please specify the number of messages to clear `e.g. !clear 10`')
            .then(message => message.delete({timeout: 3500}));

    if(!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Owner") || 
            !message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Admin") || 
            !message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Moderator")) 
        return message.reply('You do not have permissions to clear!')
            .then(message => message.delete({timeout: 3500}));

    message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
    break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make it check if the user has **neither** of the three roles.
Since you gave `||` between the `if` statements and not `&&`, it will check if the user doesn't have one or more of the three roles. If the user doesn't have one or more of them, it will output the `message.reply`.

If you give `&&` it will check if the user has none of the three roles.

P.S: there were some bracket errors and quotation errors in your provided code.

UPDATE: `"**Owner**"` has been changed to `"Owner"`

Here's the updated code:

```
case 'clear': 
            if(!args[1]) return message.reply('Please specify the number of messages to clear `e.g. !clear 10`')
            .then(message => message.delete({timeout: 3500}));
            if(!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Owner") && (!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Admin")) && (!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Moderator")) 
               {
                 return message.reply('You do not have permissions to clear!')
                 .then(message => message.delete({timeout: 3500}));
               }
            message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
            break;
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I have fixed some bugs about bracket errors and quotation errors. But when I type **!clear 10**, its show You do not have permissions to clear! and disappear for a few seconds and delete 10 latest messages. So how to not show "You do not have permissions to clear!" ?

Comment: Maybe check if your Role Names are the same in the if statement. Check if your Owner role actually does have `**Owner**`

Comment: I accidentally added `"**Owner**"` instead of `"Owner"`, check again. And do upvote my answer if your problem is solved please